# Rest-bundle of Symfony 4 requires config in 4.3 version, while Symfony 4 uses 5.0

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4, fosrestbundle

Following [this tutorial](https://www.adcisolutions.com/knowledge/getting-started-rest-api-symfony-4) I tried to configure REST API on fresh new Symfony 4 install.

The first step in the tutorial is doing:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton rest_api_project
```

Followed by

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle
```

However, when I try to install `friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle`, I get:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>     Problem 1
>       - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle ^2.6 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[2.6.0].
>       - friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.6.0 requires symfony/config ^3.4|^4.3 -> no matching package found.

So basically that this bundle requires `symfony/config ^3.4|^4.3` while Symfony 4 uses `5.0`.

How to make it work? And how this tutorial meant for Symfony 4 could even work when the `friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle` does not support config in `5.0` version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial you are using includes this as a starting point:

```
composer create-project \
    symfony/skeleton rest_api_project
```

Without a version constraint, this points to the latest version of the Symfony Skeleton. Namely, version 5.

Problem is, the FOS Rest Bundle has not been updated with Symfony 5 compatibility yet.

So you need to create the project and target version 4.

```
composer create-project\
    symfony/skeleton rest_api_project "4.*"
```

With this the versions of your dependencies are going to match.

> And how this tutorial meant for Symfony 4 could even work when the `friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle` does not support config in `5.0` version?

The tutorial is meant for Symfony 4, but you were installing Symfony 5.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I've somehow omitted that few days ago there was Symfony 5 release. Somehow I was still sure 4 is the latest version. Thank you!